# Run bash file on Windows via task scheduler

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I know there's countless post with this same question but I have not been able to get it to work by following the suggestions with installing Cygwin and running it with that.

What I'm trying to do:

- Schedule EC2 snapshots using this tool here: https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup
- Running on Windows Server 2012 R2

What I've done/tested so far:

- Installed Git
- Created a Basic Task with the Action set to "Start a program"
- Program/Script field set to "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
- Add arguments set to -l -c "C:/AWS/ec2-automate-backup.sh -v  -r  -n"

I originally thought I was entering the wrong format for the path to the shell script since Unix interprets the \ differently. I've confirmed that running the command "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -l -c "C:/AWS/ec2-automate-backup.sh -v ....." in a regular command prompt does work and a snapshot of my volume is created in AWS.

Because the above method worked, i thought maybe i should specify everything in a single line in the Program/script field. When I tried doing this the task hangs indefinitely in "the task is currently running" mode.

I also redirected any error to a snapshot.log file and noticed that it was coming up with an error message saying that "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure.". Odd this is if i open up the bash executable and run aws configure my credentials are already loaded on there. Then I thought maybe it's because the credentials are profile specific. I logged into the service account that I am using to run the task and set up the aws credentials under that account as well but am still not having any luck. If anyone has ever tried using this script to do the snapshot backups, I'd like some pointers. I know there's an easier way to do it via the AWS Lambda tool but that cost money and I really only need to do this for a couple servers so can't justify the cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into ccleaner and scheduled tasks to see how all my scheduled tasks are set up. See the image on the command that they have:

[image]

Could you try this and let me know if it works for you?

Thanks,
Deer

Comment: not really what I should be looking at but I did manage to get it to "work" somewhat. The only issue I'm having now is the scheduled task will only run if the service account is logged in. When it's not, it will run and error out and tell me it can't locate the AWS credentials.

Comment: could you use "gyazo" or some other screenshot uploader program to show me what you have set up and what is working and what the error is. this will help me narrow it down a lot more.

Comment: the blue arrows are pointing to what i think the developers figuring out how to run the tasks and skipping any errors etc... ive never seen them set up this way and i think this may be to a new microsoft patch.

Comment: ignore this question...i guess i should've looked past the first search result...powershell supports the aws cli commands so I'm going to go that route to stay native to Windows commands.

Comment: i think Microsoft released a hotfix for this, see this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133689/ubpm-doesn-t-set-environmental-variables-correctly-when-you-run-scheduled-tasks-in-windows-server-2012-r2

Comment: yeah i saw that too but it seems to reference powershell so i wasnt sure if it'd work for bash. I was going to give that a go as well.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, installing the KB3133689 hotfix listed above in @DeerSpotter's post fixed the issue. I also had to adjust my command argument from -l -c "{command}" to just -c "{command}" to run the command in a non-login shell.